# Form with dropdown select that collects data from 2 joined mysql tables and save them into 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I use a form with dropdown select that collects data from 2 left joined mysql tables (suppliers & suppliers_expenses) and save them into suppliers_expenses table. The dropdown shows the names of all suppliers and want to save the "Supplier_id" of this particular supplier. The problem is that the "Supplier_id" value is not inserted into table (only 0) but all the other values works OK. I'm stacked.

Bellow see the form i use.

---

```
<form action="insert_suppliersExpenses.php" method="post">

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("server","dbuser","123","db");
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query = "SELECT Name
FROM suppliers
LEFT JOIN suppliers_expenses
ON suppliers.Supplier_id=suppliers_expenses.Supplier_id
GROUP BY Name;"; //Write a query
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query);  //Execute the query
?>
Name: <select name="Supplier_id">
<?php
while($fetch_options = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
?>
<option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['Supplier_id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options['Supplier_id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['Name']; ?></option>
<!--Echo out options-->

<?php
}
?>
</select>
<br>
Subject: <input type="text" name="Subject"><br>
Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="datepicker" /><br>
Ammount: <input type="text" name="Ammount"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<input type="reset" value="reset">
</form>

And the php page to insert the values.
--------------------------------------

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server","dbuser","123","db");
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");

$datepicker=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO suppliers_expenses (Supplier_id, datepicker, Subject, Ammount)

VALUES ('$_POST[Supplier_id]','" . $_POST['datepicker'] . "','$_POST[Subject]','$_POST[Ammount]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "SUCCESFULL INSERTION";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to select  Supplier_id in query

try this

```
$query = "SELECT suppliers.Supplier_id,Name
FROM suppliers
LEFT JOIN suppliers_expenses
ON suppliers.Supplier_id=suppliers_expenses.Supplier_id
GROUP BY Name;"; //Write a query
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query);  //Execute the query
```

Comment: Sorry i doesn't help at all. No names are displayed in form, after "Supplier_id" in my query. My issue is that the form doesn't save the "Supplier_id" value in "suppliers_expenses" table but only "0".

Comment: both table have Supplier_id with same column name so we use table name (or alis) to select the which table column do you want to select

  check edited answer

Comment: Is there any special button to do this?

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".